# Why is my spring boot service not starting

Tags: server, permissions, java, systemd

I have a spring boot service that I'm trying to run on my Ubuntu 20.04 server.

I have created a service file in /etc/systemd/system and here is the directory entry.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  116 Jun  5 15:10 wfwweb.service
```

and here is the contents

```
[Unit]
After=network.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/wfwweb-start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Next, I created the shell script in usr/local/bin and here's that directory entry.

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 169 Jun  5 16:42 wfwweb-start.sh
```

This contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -version >> /var/log/wfwweb/wfwweb.log 2>&1 &
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev /opt/server/wfwweb-0.9.1.jar >> /var/log/wfwweb/wfwweb.log 2>&1 &
```

And finally I created a directory in /var/log and set it up for logrotate. Here is that directory entry.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-200:/var/log/wfwweb$ ls -lt
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7100 Jun  5 18:16 wfwweb.log
ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-200:/var/log/wfwweb$
```

On reboot, this is the only entry I see in syslog (relating to this).

```
Jun  5 18:17:43 ip-172-31-21-200 systemd[1]: wfwweb.service: Succeeded.
```

But the server isn't running and there is nothing in the log file.

If I then type `sudo /usr/local/bin/wfwweb-start.sh`

The server starts and the log file is filled up with messages.

So it has to be some kind of permissions thing, but I can't see it. Does anyone else?

Comment: Supposedly because `java` isn't getting recognised. Could you try redirecting `STDERR` as well in logs?

Comment: @Kulfy isn't that what 2>&1 does?

Comment: Ah yes. Missed that. Could you try setting environment, for example, `Environment=PATH=/path/to/jdk/bin` below `[Service]` since `java` is probably not in default PATH of systemd?

Comment: does `network.service` exist on your system, its usually `network.target` or `network-online.target`, maybe even both.

Comment: I don't know which kind of application you're trying to start, but since it sounds like a web-server I'd like to mention that running the service as root might be a severe security issue.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for the advice. What should I run as?

Comment: @Kulfy I added /usr/bin/ to each of the java calls and rebooted. No change.

Comment: @bac0n How do I tell?

Comment: As I said I don't know your application. The general idea is to use a user and add this user to the neccessary groups to do the job. A web-server does not need and should not have write access to system files, but will need full access to certain directories, just for example.

Comment: @mook765 and I change the owner of the shell script to accomplish this, correct?

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to add details about this application, if it's a good idea to run it as root and how should it be autostarted.

Comment: You can list them with `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service`, the unit search paths are also listed in man `systemd.unit`, the targets I mentioned are described in man `systemd.special`.

Comment: @bac0n based on your advice, I changed to `systemd-networkd.service` and it is still not putting anything in the log. Besides, if that were the problem, there wouldn't be a syslog entry, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to fork your application, you need to use `Type=forking`, or your .service will terminate as soon as the application is placed in the background.

> **Type=**
> If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. The parent
> process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the main
> service process, and the service manager will consider the unit started when the parent process exits. This is the behavior of
> traditional UNIX services. If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the PIDFile= option, so that systemd can reliably
> identify the main process of the service. systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the parent process exits.

```
[Unit]
Description=Spring boot service wfwweb
After=network.target

[Service]
SuccessExitStatus=143
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=java -version
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c \
    'exec -a wfwweb java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev /opt/server/wfwweb-0.9.1.jar &'
# User=user
#Group=group
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/wfwweb/wfwweb.log
 StandardError=append:/var/log/wfwweb/wfwweb.log
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/opt/server

[Install]
WantedBy=Multi-user.target
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of the forking. I simply removed the ampersands and it started right up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if it forks then you could probably run it directly with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar ...`